# Imprimir os arrays cujos os IDs são impares

Tags: javascript

Tenho um código com um 3 arrays, um com numeros de 0 a 10 e os outros dois com os nomes Pares e Impares.

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var pares = [];
var impares = [];
```

Usando javascript como posso dividir e armazenar os numeros em seus respectivos lugares?
(um código que funcionaria idependente do tamanho do array).

**Edit: Tentei usando .slice() mas não consegui**

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: divide os números do array  por 2. Se o resto da divisão for zero, o número é par; caso contrário, é ímpar.

Comment: como faço isso em codigo , sei uma parte mas como vou dizer que o resto da equação é 0 ? @stack.cardoso

Comment: @GabrielPatara É só usar o operador `%` (resto da divisão): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber o resto duma divisão use o [operador de resto `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) que retorna o remanescente da divisão entre dois operadores.

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var pares = [];
var impares = [];

//Para cada elemento n em arrr...
for(let n of arr){
  //Testa o resto de n dividido por 2...
  if(n % 2 == 0){
    pares.push(n);                     //...n % 2 == 0 então apensa n ao array pares.
  } else {
    impares.push(n);                   //...n % 2 <> 0 então apensa n ao array impares.
  }
}

//O operador ... chama-se sintaxe de espalhamento e permite que um objeto iterável 
//seja expandido para ser usado onde zero ou mais argumentos são esperados.
console.log("Números pares: ",...pares);
console.log("Nímeros impares: ",...impares);
```

Para mais informações veja:

[**MDN Web Docs - for...of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
[**MDN Web Docs - Sintaxe de Espalhamento**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
[**MDN Web Docs - Array.prototype.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)